# Moto E (1st Gen) Bootloader Unlocking

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, hardware, device-firmware, bootloader-lock, motorola

There was some problem with my 1-yr-old Moto E 1st gen. It got dead and after some time the dead android guy appears with some red-blue thing on its chest. It appears for half a second. I pressed Power+volume Down and menu appeared saying 'Device locked status code 0'

Somehow I unlocked it using Minimal ADB and fastboot. Then it said 'Device unlocked status code 3'. On opening it shows window saying 'Bootloader Unlocked'.

Then I tried to install firmware 'RETAIL-DSDS_CONDOR_KXC20.82-14_cid7_CFC_1FF.xml' flash images whatever they say. But in every command it returned 'Failure' and not 'Okay' as expected. Now phone is at is, with dead android guy appearing since yesterday. Please Help.

I followed steps from [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-e-2015/general/guide-restore-moto-e-2015-stock-firmware-t3044936)
[image: screenshot for first two commands]

EDIT : I downloaded another firmware named : RETAILDSDSALL_XT1022_4.4.4_KXC21.5-40_cid7_CFC.xml.zip

Again did flashing but got the same failed(remote failure) in all commands. After that I plugged out the phone and in the fastboot menu it said 'Last time flashing failed'. Now what to do ?

Answer (score 0):

This means your bootloader is not unlocked first you need to go to the sit it gives a code on your mail you have to make sure that you have enabled OEM unlocking in the settings know apply the code in minimal adb and fastboot now flash a recovery and you can flash any rom you want

Comment: I think you are talking about motorola's site, i pasted some long code there then they mailed me Unlock Key which I wrote in command prompt with required code and unlocked it.